# Parsing a lot of text based on a constant set of search terms

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a set of **search terms** like [*+dog -"jack russels" +"fox terrier"*],  [*+cat +persian -tabby*]. These could be quite long with maybe 30 sub-terms making up each term.

I now have some online news **articles** extracts such as [*"My fox terrier is the cutest dog in the world..."*] and [*"Has anyone seen my lost persian cat? He went missing ..."*]. They're not too long, perhaps 500 characters at most each.

In traditional search engines one expects a huge amount of articles that are pre-processed into indexes, allowing for speed-ups when searching given 'search terms', using set theory/boolean logic to reduce articles to only ones that match the phrases. In this situation, however, the order of my search terms is ~10^5, and I'd like to be able to process a single article at a time, to see ALL the sets of search terms that article would be  matched with (i.e. all the **+** terms are in the text and none of the **-** terms).

I have a possible solution using two maps (one for the positive sub-phrases, one for the negative sub-phrases), but I don't think it'll be very efficient.

First prize would be a library that solves this problem, second prize is a push in the right direction towards solving this.

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? There might be a better solution...

Comment: What's your problem? What did you do so far?

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695826/compound-queries-with-redis - the approach I used for that seemed to work well for me.  Redis is efficient at using minimal memory so it may be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the positive sub-terms are required for a match:

Put all the sub-terms from your search terms into a hashtable. The sub-term is the key, the value is a pointer to the full search term data structure (which should include a unique id and a map of sub-terms to a boolean).

Additionally, when processing a news item, create a "candidates" map, indexed by the term id. Each candidate structure has a pointer to the term definition, a set that contains the seen sub-terms and a "rejected" flag.

Iterate over the words of the news article.

For each hit, look up the candidate entry. If not there, create and add an empty one.

If the candidate rejection flag is set, you are done.

Otherwise, look up the sub-term from the term data structure.
If negative, set the rejected flag.
If positive, add the sub-term to the set of seen sub-terms.

In the end, iterate over the candidates. All candidates that are not rejected and where the size of the seen set equals to the number of positive sub-terms of that term are your hits.

Implementation: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1boieLJboLTy7X2NH1Grybik4ERTpDtFVggjZeEDQH74/edit

Runtime is O(n * m) where n is the number of words in the article and m is the maximum number of terms sharing the same sub-term (expected to be relatively small).

Comment: I actually spent some time this weekend on this problem and got a similar solution. I think one memory optimization I did was ensure each word in the article was unique (using a 'seen' hashmap); and then instead of using sets for candidates I could just use a byte.

Comment: A byte identifying the word in the article? Or use it as a bit set to encode seen? BTW: you may want to use String.intern() when reading the filters if you don't already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think making a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of your document makes the searching much faster since you need to built it once, but you may use it as many times as the length of your query is.

Second, you need to iterate all of the search terms (both + and - ones) to make sure if the answer is yes (that is the document matches the query). However, for a "no" answer, you dont! If the answer is no, then the order of matching the search terms against the document really matters. That is one order may give you a faster "no" than another order. Now the question is "What is the optimal order to get a fast NO?". It really depends on the application, but a good starting point is that multi-word terms such as "red big cat" are less commonly repeated in the documents compared to short terms such as "cat" and vice versa. So, go with +"Loo ooo ooo ooo ooo ong" and -"short" terms first.

Comment: Each document will only be parsed once to see matching "search terms" - preprocessing this won't help at all.